# Is "the photo I had taken" correct?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Which of the following sentences is correct:

> I've just uploaded the photo I had taken on Monday.
>
> I've just uploaded the photo I took on Monday.

I guess that this sentence

> Yesterday I uploaded the photo I had taken on Monday.

is correct but has different meaning than the first two.

Comment: This is proofreading. But both sentences are correct. They do (or can) mean different things, though. What meaning do you want to convey? [[Edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/146137/edit) to add more context]

Comment: @AndrewLeach, could you explain the difference between the first two?

Comment: @espertus See my comment on Fumblefingers' answer, and indeed his [edited] answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I can't exactly explain why, but it seems to me including the word ***just*** (which in principle is syntactically irrelevant) makes Past Perfect more acceptable than it would have been. Consider...

> 1a: *?I have spent the money I had earned yesterday.*
>    2a: *I have spent the money I earned yesterday.*
>
> 1b: *?I do not have the money I had earned yesterday.*
>    2b: *I do not have the money I earned yesterday.*

With the construction reduced to its bare essentials like that, I'd have no hesitation in saying that *linguistically*, #1a / #1b are at the very least ["unhappy"](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2742896) (most native speakers wouldn't like them). And prescriptive grammarians would doubtless say the tense mismatch is "ungrammatical".

---

As @Andrew comments below, OP's #1 might not be a Past Perfect usage at all. It could be Simple Past *to **have** [something] XXXXed = to **cause** [something] to be XXXXed* (by someone else)...

> We had our wedding pictures taken by a professional photographer.

To clarify the different usages, consider...

> *Yesterday I cut my hair.* (Simple Past - I did it myself)
>    *Yesterday I **had** my hair cut.*  (Simple Past - I got someone else to cut it)
>    *Yesterday I looked smart because I **had cut** my hair.*  (Past Perfect)

Note that the potential "ambiguity" of OP's #1 is an artefact of the written form. In "real" language (i.e. - the *spoken* form), if the Simple Past sense was intended, the word ***had*** would be stressed. That stress would unambiguously identify ***to have*** as the "primary" verb, rather than just the "helper" verb used to form the Past Perfect.

Comment: Just to add a little piquancy into the mix, *to have taken* (as an infintive phrasal verb) can mean *to cause to be taken,* which is why both the example sentences are correct and mean different things.

Comment: @Andrew: You're right, of course. I don't suppose for one moment that OP intends that sense (which would sound *very* different in spoken form), but I'll edit my answer to cover it.

Comment: For more complete completeness, you could also add *Yesterday I looked smart because I had had my hair cut.* (past perfect, got someone else to cut it)

Comment: @Hellion: What I really wanted to come up with was a "subject-object-verb" sequence, so I wouldn't have to tinker with the word order in my final three examples. Even though I don't actually know any examples, I'm sure many other languages would have the equivalent of *I my hair cut*. But I don't feel too bad about not being able to think of an English version (or indeed, not knowing for sure if there *is* one). I'm still basking in the self-satisfaction of recognising that this "ambiguity" is peculiar to the *written* form, not a feature of "real" English.

Comment: ...but I'm a bit disappointed everyone else wants to close this as proofreading. I have the definite sense that OP's ***just*** somehow muddies the waters in respect of reference time, and I was rather hoping there'd be some follow-up on that point.